# Send Email action did not appear in Salesforce1

Tags: salesforce1-app

i followed the steps [here](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/he-il/summer14/release-notes/rn_mobile_salesforce1_send_email_action.htm) to add in Email Action for Salesforce1 user to send email from their tablet/smart phones. I have added the Send Email action to all my case page layout but in my Salesforce1 i do not see this action on the case.

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

EDIT:
If i login from mobile website to Salesforce then I am able to see the Send Email Action. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, solved. I had to uninstall the Salesforce1 mobile apps and re-install again and the Send Email Action appeared.

Thanks.